# docker module.js:550 throw err; ^

Tags: docker

I try to run the application in Docker, with the installation of dependencies, from a private repository, but I get this error.

Start docker container docker run -p 3000:80

```
module.js:550
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'debug'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:548:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:475:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/src/server.js:5:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
```

my Dockerfile

install using YARN

```
FROM node:8

ENV YARN_VERSION 1.16.0

ARG SSH_PRIVATE_KEY
RUN mkdir -p /root/.ssh
RUN echo $SSH_PRIVATE_KEY > /root/.ssh/id_rsa && chmod 600 /root/.ssh/id_rsa
RUN ssh-keyscan -H bitbucket.org >> /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts

RUN curl -fSLO --compressed "https://yarnpkg.com/downloads/$YARN_VERSION/yarn-v$YARN_VERSION.tar.gz" \
    && tar -xzf yarn-v$YARN_VERSION.tar.gz -C /opt/ \
    && ln -snf /opt/yarn-v$YARN_VERSION/bin/yarn /usr/local/bin/yarn \
    && ln -snf /opt/yarn-v$YARN_VERSION/bin/yarnpkg /usr/local/bin/yarnpkg \
    && rm yarn-v$YARN_VERSION.tar.gz


COPY package*.json ./

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "node", "server.js" ]
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "test-home-nodejs",
  "description": "",
  "version": "1.17.2",
  "author": "",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "test": "NODE_ENV=test node node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha --recursive -R mocha-bamboo-reporter",
    "watchTests": "NODE_ENV=test ./node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js watch-pot"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git@bitbucket.org:igorbell/test-home.git"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "async": "^1.1.0",
    "autosize": "^4.0.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.25.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babelify": "^7.3.0",
    "bluebird": "^3.0.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.9.0",
    "bower": "^1.3.3",
    "browserify": "^13.0.1",
    "browserify-shim": "^3.8.11",
    "chalk": "^1.1.0",
    "chosen-js": "^1.7.0",
    "client-sessions": "^0.7.0",
    "cloudinary": "~1.9.0",
    "coffeeify": "2.0.1",
    "compression": "^1.4.3",
```

configured according to this instruction
[enter link description here](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/master/docs/BestPractices.md)

When using the NMP, there was almost the same error

**UPDATE in dockerfile**

```
ARG NODE_ENV=qa
ENV NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV}
```

Comment: how you start the container? share the command

Comment: root@HP:/home/bell/downloads/Iqonic/Docker/test4/ziva-home# docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
test2               latest              8fb4a8795fda        7 seconds ago       802MB
node                8-jessie            0f8964092ab1        4 months ago        681MB
root@HP:/home/bell/downloads/Iqonic/Docker/test4/ziva-home# docker run -p 3000:80 8fb4a8795fda
module.js:550
    throw err;
    ^

Comment: You need to do a yarn install between the two `COPY` else you will miss some dependencies. If you already run a yarn install outside Docker, you should ignore the directory and make a fresh install instead as some package are system dependents.